# Update object inside a multiprocessing.Manager.dict()

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, shared

I was wondering how I could update an object assigned as a shared dictionary value between different process. I have the following class:

```py
class Task:

    STATUS_PROCESSING = 0
    STATUS_EXECUTING = 1
    STATUS_QUEUED = 2
    STATUS_TERMINATED = 3
    STATUS_HALTED = 4
    STATUS_STOPPED = 5

    def __init__(self, id: str, uuid: str, options: dict):
        self.id = id
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.options = options
        self.state = 0

    # Some properties...

    def execute(self):
        """ Executes the task
        """
        # Set self status to Executing
        self.state = Task.STATUS_EXECUTING

        print('Executing...')

        self.state = Task.STATUS_TERMINATED
```

It just creates a new task with a given ID and executes its core method when `execute()` is called. I have another class with staticmethods that is used to append a new pair (id, task) to the dict, and read the dict executing all its tasks until the main program stops:

```py
class DummyList:

    @staticmethod
    def submit_task(d: dict, uuid: str, options: dict):
        """ Submit a new task
        """
        # If invalid UUID
        if not Task.is_valid_uuid(uuid):
            return False

        # If more than 20 tasks
        if len(d) > 19:
            return False

        # Create random ID (simplified for question)
        r_id = str(random.randint(1, 2000000))
        if r_id in d:
            return False

        # Add task to the dictionary
        d[r_id] = Task(r_id, uuid, options)

        # Set status to queue
        d[r_id].state = Task.STATUS_QUEUED

        # Return the created ID
        return r_id

    @staticmethod
    def execute_forever(d):
        try:
            while True:
                for i in d.values():
                    print(i.state)
                    i.execute()
                time.sleep(5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

The thing is that the `DummyList.execute_forever()` will be called from another process, while the main one will execute the `submit_task(...)` function to add new tasks. Like this:

```py
        # Create a shared dict
        m = multiprocessing.Manager()
        shared_d = m.dict()

        # Start the Task shared list execution in another process
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=DummyList.execute_forever, args=(shared_d,))
        # Set the process to exit when the main halts
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

        ........


       # From another place
       # The message variable is not important
       DummyList.submit_task(shared_d, message['proc'], message['options'])
```

It works! The task is created, assigned to the dictionary and executed, but the following lines (which are seen in the above code) do not execute properly:

```py
self.state = Task.STATUS_EXECUTING
self.state = Task.STATUS_TERMINATED
d[r_id].state = Task.STATUS_QUEUED
```

**If we would try to write `ìf shared_d[<some_id>].state == 0` all over the code, it will always be `True`, because the property does not update**

I suppose that's because the shared dictionary does not update when the object properties are modified, maybe because the dictionary only understands he has to update when his **getitem** or **setitem** methods are called. Do you know if there is any way to change this behaivor?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The objects inside the dictionary were not updating unless the `__getitem__` or `__setitem__` methods from the proxy dictionary were called. That's why I changed the following lines:

## Task

The `execute()` method ends with `return self`. The `self.state` must be changed throughout the execution.

## TaskManager

Method changed to:

```py
@staticmethod
    def execute_forever(d):
        """ Infinite loop reading the queued tasks and executing all of them.
        """
        try:
            while True:
                # Notice the loop using the keys
                for i in d.keys():
                    # Execute and re-assign item
                    d[i] = d[i].execute()
                time.sleep(5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```